# How to horizontally slide divs, without position:absolute

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I have a two panel view where only one panel is visible at any given time. Whenever a panel disappears it should slide to the right, and at the same time the appearing  panel should slide in from the left. Whenever I animate one div displays above the other when they should both be on the same line transitioning. The container cannot have an overflow-y property since the divs might vary in length and for the same reason the divs cannot be position:absolute (since I do not know the height). [Here is a fiddle at regular speed](https://jsfiddle.net/alanzam2223/sbyLqtv7/)

the css for the container

```
.selectedContent
{
min-height:140px;
padding:4px 10px;
width:300px;
background:white;
text-align:center;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
```

[Here is the fiddle slowed down](https://jsfiddle.net/alanzam2223/qhht7b8f/)

I slowed down the fiddle so you can clearly see that the divs display on top of each other and not side by side. I tried to float them so that they could display inline but that did not work.

Comment: Why does the variable content size have any effect on being able to use position absolute?

Comment: Visual description is strongly required I think

Comment: @Trix I linked the fiddle

Comment: Because position:absolute will not influence the container's height, therefore in order for the content to be visible, you have to set a literal height, something that I cannot do since the child divs can have variable heights